# When finding a successor for a node deletion in a BST, can there two answers?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Take the BST below as example:

[image: Example BST]

If I were to theoretically remove the root (15), I find that the different sources give me two different methods to find the successor.

- Case 1: Take the Leftmost value of the Right Child (Successor of 15 = 16)
- Case 2: Take the Rightmost value of the Left Child (Predecessor of 15 = 13)

Both return valid BSTs after the appropriate shifts, but is there a more CORRECT answer? Or are both answers technically correct?

I'm asking this question from a primarily conceptional point of view for my algorithms class, but if there's any advantages to each method from an implementation point of view, I'd love to know as well!

Comment: I edited the question with correct successor and predecessor relations.  NB: both are just fine.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between the two (Both methods are correct and have the same complexity), and deciding which method to use is purely an implementation decision.

When we remove a parent node(e.g. 15) that has a left and right subtree, in order to maintain the BST properties (all nodes in its left are smaller than the parent, and all nodes in its right are bigger than the parents), Case 1 and Case 2(Predecessor and Successor as you mentioned)  are the only two nodes that we can replace the parent with (making all the other nodes the parent will fail to meet the BST properties).

Unless your BST has some special structures, e.g. if your BST will always have less nodes on left side, than traverse down the right subtree and get the left most would be more efficient. However, no difference for a general BST.